# Laravel/GCP Error: Could not construct ApplicationDefaultCredentials

Tags: php, laravel, google-cloud-platform, google-secret-manager

I am trying to deploy a Laravel application using GithubCI to Google Container Registry. In the application, I created a helper function to get secrets from Google Secret Manager. This is the code.

```
if (!function_exists('get_secret')) {
    function get_secret(string $name, $version = 'latest'): string
    {
        $client = new SecretManagerServiceClient();
        $name = $client->secretVersionName(
            env('GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT_ID', '*****'),
            $name,
            $version,
        );

        $request =  AccessSecretVersionRequest::build($name);
        $response = $client->accessSecretVersion($request);
        $payload  = $response->getPayload()->getData();
        return $payload;
    }
}
```

Then I used the function in the relevant config files. (e.g. database.php, app.php)
And it works fine on my local machine. The problem is that when I try to build the application using docker on GithubCI, I get the following error

[image: GithubCI Error]

This is my Github Workflow

```
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    permissions:
      contents: "read"
      id-token: "write"
    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - id: "auth"
        name: "Authenticate to Google Cloud"
        uses: "google-github-actions/auth@v1"
        with:
          workload_identity_provider: "${{ secrets.WIP }}"
          service_account: "${{ secrets.SERVICE_ACCOUNT }}"

      - name: "Set up Cloud SDK"
        uses: "google-github-actions/setup-gcloud@v1"

      - name: "Configure docker to use use gcloud"
        run: |-
          gcloud auth configure-docker --quiet

      - name: Set up Docker Buildx
        uses: docker/setup-buildx-action@v2

      - name: Build and push EPMS Worker
        uses: docker/build-push-action@v4
        with:
          context: .
          file: worker.Dockerfile
          push: true
          tags: gcr.io/fabled-mystery-328210/fbasegithub/epms-worker:latest
```